# Resolution of Recaptcha Error in Drupal 7 forms

Tags: 7, advertising

I am using Recaptcha module for filtering the spam on the form. 
But the form contains some alax file upload field which stop recaptcha to work properly. Every time I upload the file in the form by AJAX it is giving me following message:

CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected.

This made me difficult to use the module. Please let me know if there is any work around to solve the problem.

I am just newbie in Drupal 7. If there is any better spam protection module than recaptcha then also suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I personally use the [Are You a Human PlayThru Module](https://drupal.org/project/ayah):</del>

> PlayThru is designed to be more simple, more intuitive, and more fun than other CAPTCHA options. We use game mechanics to create an experience that’s more enjoyable than figuring out what that awful squiggly text says.
>
> PlayThru is also more secure. Because users interact directly with PlayThru, we can analyze that interaction and track the resulting data to generate a Human Confidence Score: our level of confidence that a user is an actual human.

<del>You can also check out a video about it this module here:</del>

<del>[Drupal 7 Are You a Human PlayThru Module - Daily Dose of Drupal episode 78](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awn5S5NDWVc)</del>

## Update

The Are you a human PlayThru service has shutdown, I recommend you go with [ReCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha)

> Uses the Google reCAPTCHA web service to improve the CAPTCHA system
> and protect email addresses.
>
> reCAPTCHA helps power massive-scale online collaboration.